# How can I programmatically update environment config file for firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to update some parameters that I keep in the config file for the Firebase functions via programs such that without me needing to manually deploy the function again the parameters value is updated and the appropriate functions are deployed again.

I have tried Google Cloud Build and Cloud Run. I can re deploy a function but I can't seem to be able to update the config.json before deploying the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change any of the content or configuration after deployment without deploying again.  If you require dynamically modifiable configuration, you're going to have to provide that for yourself via a database query or something that the function can do at runtime to see if there is an update